# Multiple flask processes with a shared resource

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, microservices

Multiple flask processes (managed by gunicorn) serve the frontend and have to use a shared resource: A data structure that allows reads and updates and therefore needs to be protected by a simple (or RW) lock.

**What options do I have regarding the communication between web frontend and data structure?** I already had a look at the following libraries:

- pyZMQ. I'm held back by the problem that arises when the service is restarting while the client is expecting data. Also I would need to implement method calling, de-/serialization and the like.
- https://github.com/0rpc/zerorpc-python This is an additional layer around pyZMQ and works around this issue but seems not very actively developed and I don't want to be forced to use gevent.
- Pyro. Seems to provide the functionality I need (using a single instance or python threads for the service). Might be a bit heavyweight for my needs.
- socketserver. Pretty lowlevel but might also do what I want as long as I implement method calling, de-/serialization, ...

Are there better options?

Comment: Try Scapy https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Comment: "Scapy is a [...] interactive packet manipulation program and library." I'm not sure that this will help me...

Comment: I understand that this question is very specific to my problem, but I really don't have a clue "how it is done the right way". So why not add a comment when downvoting?